# How does the wormhole generator work in Metal Gear Online?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-online

Typically in a match of MGO I'll get an announcement that the wormhole generator is available. I've found it in my inventory, but haven't been able to get it to work. What does this item do, and how can I use it efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wormhole can be used when you buddy link with a teammate (Saluting or being in close proximity with them until the circle icon fills up). Using it will place a wormhole on the ground. Stepping into it will teleport you to the teammate that you linked with.

Comment: So this is separate from the Buddy Link system? Can it also send you to your buddy if you charge it with them? Does it persist through death? Not trying to poke holes in your answer, just hoping to get the full picture :)

Comment: @twobugs Updated my answer to be a bit clearer - What I meant by charging was buddy linking ;) I'm not sure if it persists post death of you or your teammate though..

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll try to test that out with my friends tonight!